# tsql while loop and time issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I dont know what is wrong with my query but it is not breaking out of while loop. I think it is how I am doing calculation for time but not sure.

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = GETDATE(), @currenttime INT = 0

while @currenttime <= 1 --- represent min
begin

    [execute Query]

    ' this will always return 0 and keep executing query even though the 1 min has been reached
    set @currenttime = CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(s, @start, GETDATE())%3600/60) 
end
```

Comment: It looks like the while loop will execute for 2 minutes.  The check is for while the @currenttime is less than or equal to 1.

Comment: s means second in date diff -- just use `set @currenttime = DTEDIFF(s, @start, GETDATE())`

Comment: @Hogan, so this will check for second? If so, I need it to be for mins.

Comment: @Hogan, wow. You serious about your comment? Did you not read my post, i said my calculation may be off. Of course I know to use "mi". I just wanted to make sure i am getting the correct info. I guess everywhere you go, there are really assholes around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL While Loop 60 seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433055/sql-while-loop-60-seconds)

Comment: @user1884032 -- actually your question was quite unclear.  At no point do you say what you want to do.  I have no way of knowing what you are trying to do -- I do know that using "s" and then moduls 60 makes no sense and that is what my comment pointed to -- I said that s means second.  You then ask me if this is checking for second.  Which of us is not reading?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it is to change the condition of the while loop:

```
SELECT @Start = GETDATE()

WHILE DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Start, GETDATE()) < 3 -- Execute the loop for 3 seconds
BEGIN

SELECT 1

END
```

Comment: I think this is an easier to understand template.

Comment: @Hogan me to, that's why I've written it. It's much more readable when you don't have to look for the values making up the condition somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Is this a reliable way to run a loop for a period of time? When I execute this on a local SQL 2016 Express instance, it runs for anywhere between 12 and 15 seconds...

Comment: I'm with you @3N1GM4

Comment: I didn't test it extensively, only once, so I don't know. The time is dependent of course on the content of the loop.

Comment: well try select getdate() or select 1... so the inner statement has to take more than second for it not to be infinite?

Answer (score 3):

Instead try calculating the end time and looping until it is reached

```
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME
SET @EndTime = DATEADD(SECOND, 5, GETDATE())

WHILE GETDATE() < @EndTime
BEGIN

    PRINT CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), @EndTime) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' Seconds Remaining' 

END
```

Comment: This gives me a reliable runtime of the expected number of seconds, unlike [Zohar Peled's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42007296/5669294). +1

Comment: @3N1GM4 - functionally this is not connecting to the db and the other answer is -- so maybe you have a bad/slow network?

Comment: @Hogan Seems unlikely as the SQL instance I was connected to was local to my physical machine. In any case, if a suggestion in an answer could perform differently depending on network bandwidth and/or latency, I would suggest that impacts the usefulness of that solution, hence my comment.

Comment: @3N1GM4  -- they don't do the same thing -- one is a select statement and one is a print.  Put the print in the first one, what happens?

Comment: In either case you will be calling GETDATE(). The content of the loop in both answers is just an example and will be the same in the actual implementation

Comment: @Hogan I understand, but if the question is "How can I get a loop to run for [x] seconds?" and an answer which has been provided may or may not run for [x] seconds depending on the exact content of the loop (and doesn't explain this in the answer), then it's not a great answer IMO.

Comment: @3N1GM4 -- I understand the question is "Re-run content if it ran for less than X minutes."  Maybe we read different questions.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433055/sql-while-loop-60-seconds) to a similar question, if you wanted to run your script once a second for 60 seconds for example:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1;

WHILE (@i <= 60)
 BEGIN
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

       /*Your Script*/

 SET  @i = @i + 1;
END
```